# Añadir Update y Delete a Controller en MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc

Buenas, estoy trabajando en un proyecto en MVC4, hasta ahora puedo ir a la base de datos y consultar información, mi duda es: cual es la forma mas directa de realizar `update` y `delete`?

Quiero en lo posible evitar armar clausulas SQL de forma manual. 
Estuve viendo que el método mas rápido seria algo así:

```
        Entidad nuevoRegistro = new Entidad() { id = "50094", Disabled = false }; //los datos id y disabled no tienen importancia
        Context.Entidad.Add(nuevoRegistro);
        Context.SaveChanges();
```

Sin embargo cuando lo ejecuto me da error de valor null no controlado. 
¿Alguno sabe que puede estar mal o conocer un camino mejor para un update/delete?

Comment: Yo lo veo bien. Te sugiero verificar otros datos en la tabla. Puede ser que estés tratando de agregar un valor y la tabla no admita null en ese campo.

Comment: Probe completando todos los campos de la tabla y sigue con ese error. Alguna idea de que puede ser? El mensaje es: "Se produjo una excepción de tipo 'System.NullReferenceException'"

Comment: Es posible que haya intentado utilizar un objeto sin usar primero la palabra clave New por ejemplo en la clase de contexto o un objeto cuyo valor está establecido en nulo. Si no es el caso recomiendo yo colocaría el código en un bloque Try.  Para tener mas información del error.

Comment: Creo que tienes dos temas diferentes en tu pregunta. Una es porque falla el insert (o add), y la otra es como hacer el update y delete.
En lo que respecta al insert, tu tabla tiene llave primaria autonúmerica?